# NAND jffs2 files system - binary & text files can exceeds the size of NAND

Tags: arm, jffs2

I am writing an embedded application based on the ARM 9 v5 processor, and am using 64MB NAND. My problem is that when I copy the text or binary files of size 3-4 MB, the free physical memory gets reduced by only few KB, whereas `ls -l` shows the file size in MB.

By repeating the same process I reached one point where `df` command shows me **10MB** size is free and `du` shows the total size as **239MB**.

I have only **64MB** of NAND, how am I able to add files up to 239MB of size?

Answer (score 0):

JFFS2 is a compressed filesystem, so it is keeping the files compressed in the disk, which leads to this conflict. `du` lists the disk usage and `df` is the available capacity as seen by the filesystem.